# Problems with deploying GWT with RPC to tomcat (web.xml problem probably)

Tags: gwt, servlets, rpc, web.xml

My gwt app that uses mysql database runs normaly in eclipse when debugging. When i run it on tomcat, it displays correctly but when i click on a button that makes a RPC (executes servlet and contacts the database) i get an error. I checked my tomcat log and i see 404 error when clicking on a button:

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [22/Jul/2010:10:32:39 +0200] "GET /Bazica/war/Bazica.html HTTP/1.1" 304 -
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [22/Jul/2010:10:32:39 +0200] "GET /Bazica/war/Bazica.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [22/Jul/2010:10:32:39 +0200] "GET /Bazica/war/bazica/bazica.nocache.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [22/Jul/2010:10:32:39 +0200] "GET /Bazica/war/bazica/    F0C186B415ADBD43522C686552368517.cache.html HTTP/1.1" 304 -
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [22/Jul/2010:10:32:39 +0200] "GET /Bazica/war/bazica/gwt/standard/images/hborder.png    HTTP/1.1" 304 -
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [22/Jul/2010:10:33:29 +0200] "POST /Bazica/war/bazica/greet HTTP/1.1" 404 1024
```

I guess this is a problem with web.xml file and url-pattern. I guess i don't understand this url-pattern,  where should it point to?

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>

 <!-- Servlets -->
 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>com.test.baze.server.GreetingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/bazica/greet</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <!-- Default page to serve -->
 <welcome-file-list>
 <welcome-file>Bazica.html</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>

 </web-app>
```

My interface has an annotation RemoteServiceRelativePath("greet"), i think it's relevant:

```
package com.test.baze.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;

/**
* The client side stub for the RPC service.
*/
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("greet")
public interface GreetingService extends RemoteService {
String greetServer(String name) throws IllegalArgumentException;
}
```

I tried changing url-pattern to the folder of my service implementation /WEB-INF/classes/com/test/baze/server but my app hangs with no message.
Could you please help me change my web.xml or sth. else to get my app working on a Tomcat. Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a [look at the docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideImplementingServices), your URL pattern should be:

```
<url-pattern>/module_name/greet</url-pattern>
```

But in your web.xml, you've set the module name to "bazica". Are you [renaming the module](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModuleXml) in your GWT module file (.gwt.xml file) to bazica? If you're not, you'll either have to rename it or use the full path to the GWT module file.

Comment: Yes i renamed my module to "bazica" (<module rename-to='bazica'>). 

What else could be wrong?

Comment: Do i need to add <inherits ...> line to module description?

Comment: Can you edit your post above and add your gwt module code too?